# Would it be permissible for me to translate a hadeeth, from English to Bosnian?

Tags: translation

As-salaamu 'alaykum, wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuh.

I am an English speaker, whose native language is Bosnian.

Currently, I am also learning Arabic. In the meantime, I am writing about Islam, in the Bosnian language.

It may be difficult for me to find an authentic translation of a hadeeth in the Bosnian language, as I do not have access to a set of works by one of the six imams, translated in Bosnian. In addition, finding these ahadeeth on the internet has also been difficult.

My question is: Would I be able to translate an English version, into the Bosnian language, since I would not know how to translate it from Arabic to Bosnian?

Comment: I can't say it would be permissible, but you must understand that translation is always an **interpretation** so at least you may always miss a nuance from the original or maybe a special hidden meaning! So if the translation is for your use that could be fine, but if it is for others you have a long "way" with one "side road" between original and final translation were you may have missed or lost a lot of useful baggage and information, and this is a big responsability you must be aware of!

Comment: It depends on what Hadith. But I  wouldn't recommend it at all.

Comment: As Medi1saif mentioned its interpretation and right now you are learning Arabic so its necessary to take help of a person who is mastered on both Arabic and bosnian language.May Allah Swt help you in this biggest and nice cause.

Answer (score 1):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

As you said, **you don't have access to the authentic translations**, and it sounds like there are some authentic translations.

So, you should **try to have access to them anyway if you want to quote some ahadees translated in your writings, which others might read**.

I think i can safely say that if you are good in bosnian and english booth, than you can surely translate the authentic english translation in bosnian. And **to verfiy your translation, you can ask some other boosnian to translate it back to english(without him knowing original english translation text), and than verify this from some authentic person that if this translation is good enough.**

But your **first preference should be to find some proper authentic translations as you mentioned they exist**.

All the **things we do depends on our intentions**, so you need to worry too much, just give your best, and **mention this is as of my translation, and these might not be perfect.** If your intentions are right, and you have done whatever you can to prevent any wrong translation, than you are safe.

### Allah knows best

Comment: So you would recommend using a translation as basis for an other translation: Ar->En->Bosnian. Do you know how much information you would loose at the end? I mean if he isn't an expert i wouldn't even recommend an Arabic-> Bosnian translation!

Comment: @Medi1Saif their should be no obstacle in spreading deen. If he is good in english and boosnian, i think he can translate, as in my answer i suggested some other things too. Like verifying it by letting someone else translate it back to english and verify it still with some proper authoritative person, also still write besides his translation that it is his translation and can have some unconscious errors. Also i aksed him to first try his best to get to proper translations already done.

Answer (score 0):

Your best route would be to find someone who speaks both Arabic and Bosnian and work from that route.

We are dealing with Hadith, so this is not a light manner. If you take an English translation of the original Hadith in Arabic, translate it to Bosnian, then what will occur when a brother decides to translate your work into Chechen? It’s bad enough that many English translation of Arabic work fail to capture the rhetoric and intricacies of the Arabic language, now consider the dangers when this occurs to a Hadith three or four times over.

This is not to discourage you, but to encourage rather to exercise caution if you choose to translate the Hadith from English to Bosnian. Use your understanding of the Arabic language to the best of your ability in the process, and if you can, add a disclaimer that the translations are your own work. It seems to be a matter of necessity since you have no access to any work in the Bosnian language. This is a good opportunity to earn blessings, you can sharpen your school and provide Bosnian translations that will benefit the entire Ummah of that language. Wow. May Allah grant you success in your efforts!! Just be cautious and only perform your work in a state of Wudu. Send constant salaams on Nabi Sallallahu Alayhi Wasallam while you are working as well.